# How to compute frequency of concurrent events by combination in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, count, inner-join

I am looking for a way to identify event names names that co-occur: i.e., correlate event names with the same start (startts) and end (endts) times: the events are exactly concurrent (partial overlap is not a feature of this data base).

toy dataframe

```
+------------------+
|name startts endts|
| A   02:20  02:23 |
| A   02:23  02:25 |
| A   02:27  02:28 |
| B   02:20  02:23 |
| B   02:23  02:25 |
| B   02:25  02:27 |
| C   02:27  02:28 |
| D   02:27  02:28 |
| D   02:28  02:31 |
| E   02:27  02:28 |
| E   02:29  02:31 |
+------------------+
```

Ideal output:

```
+---------------------------+
|combination| count         |
+---------------------------+
|  AB       | 2             |
|  AC       | 1             |
|  AE       | 1             |
|  AD       | 1             |
|  BC       | 0             |
|  BD       | 0             |
|  BE       | 0             |
|  CE       | 0             |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Naturally, I would have tried a loop but I recognize mysql server is not optimal for this.

What I've tried is generating a temporary table by selecting for distinct name and startts and endts combinations and then doing a left join on the table itself (selecting name).

Thank you.

Comment: mysql stored procedures can lops as can mysql 8 with cte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this as a self-join, aggregation, and a conditional count of matching intervals:

```
select t1.name name1, t2.name name2,
    sum(t1.startts = t2.startts and t1.endts = t2.endts) cnt
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t2.name > t1.name
group by t1.name, t2.name
order by t1.name, t2.name
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=602c40f6e1d7d73e5bb384cc8955c956)**:

```
name1 | name2 | cnt
:---- | :---- | --:
A     | B     |   2
A     | C     |   1
A     | D     |   1
A     | E     |   1
B     | C     |   0
B     | D     |   0
B     | E     |   0
C     | D     |   1
C     | E     |   1
D     | E     |   1
```

Note that, if you are looking for a count of *overlapping* intervals, all you have to do is change the `sum()` to:

```
sum(t1.startts <= t2.endts and t1.endts >= t2.startts) cnt
```

Comment: Thanks; when I run this solution, I get the following message:

"Invalid operation: function sum(boolean) does not exist; [SQL State=42883, DB Errorcode=500310]: 1 statement failed."


I circumvented this by casting (t1.startts = t2.startts and t1.endts = t2.endts) to 1 or zero using a case statement;

However, how do I do an inner join on filtered table?

Comment: example: 


select top 10 t1.name name1, t2.name name2,
 sum(case when t1.startts = t2.startts and t1.endts = t2.endts then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from mytable t1 **where columnA=Y**
inner join mytable as t2 on t2.name > t1.name **where columnA=Y**
group by t1.name, t2.name
order by t1.name, t2.name

Comment: MySQL version = PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.19097

Comment: @SadCampCounselor: why did you tag your question MySQL if you are running Postgres? These are two different databases, with different features...

Comment: Forgive I'm a noob. Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't realize that. I thought they were virtually identical until now.

I think I got your solution working though, with the modification below. It's been running for 7 minutes now, it is a big database though. Fingers crossed. 


```
select top 10 t1.name name1, t2.name name2,
 sum(case when t1.startts = t2.startts and t1.endts = t2.endts then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from mytable t1
inner join mytable as t2 on t2.name > t1.name
where t1.farmid = 125 and t2.farmid= 125
group by t1.name, t2.name
order by t1.name, t2.name
```

Comment: @SadCampCounselor: generating all combinations is expensive, there is no easy way around this... If you have performance issues, then you might want to ask a new question. I think the question you asked was anwered here.